# Create an Extension that is Identical to the Built-in Chrome Bookmarks Manager with Additional Features

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, chromium, bookmarks

### Background

I understand there is a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619884/editing-built-in-chrome-bookmarks-manager-folder-sub-folder-auto-expansion). But I could not do a follow-up comment because I don't have enough reputation yet... since I just recently joined.

### Goal

I would like to create an extension that adds two things onto the current built-in chrome bookmark manager that would appear right below the URL box in the pop-up when you do star(bookmark) and click more. (could not post an image again because of reputation limit) First is a box for note-taking, where the notes will be searchable and editable within the bookmark manager. Second is another box for setting up a reminder to remind user to view the bookmark (very simple - only allows date and time)

### Question

I don't want to drastically change anything about the current pop-up nor the manager. So I'm trying to avoid creating an extension from scratch. Instead, I wonder if extracting the relevant code from Chromium [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/bookmarks/) is feasible/legal as I don't have much experience in open-sourced projects? And then build on top of that to create an extension that basically is the same as the built-in bookmark manager but with additional features. Thank you!

### Current state

I'm still looking at the Chromium [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/resources/bookmarks/). And I will update this post if I have any progress.

Comment: Extensions can't modify the built-in UI in Chome. Extensions can replace the bookmark **adding** UI completely but only when a [special command line switch is specified](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/ui_override). To reiterate: the manager is off-limits. Well, unless you want a personal extension that you can run on chrome:// URLs using `--extensions-on-chrome-urls` command line switch.

Comment: I see. And thank you for the link. But I'm not trying to modify nor replace the built-in UI. I'm trying to create an extension that is exactly the same as the built-in one, but with additional features. Sorry for the confusion I think updating the title might help.

Comment: In that case you can probably reuse the built-in one, but you'll have to polyfill/replace/delete all the internal API it uses (things like chrome.somethingPrivate).

Comment: That makes sense. I'll give it a try. Thanks!